# extract last row for each subject from a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R like this. I would like to extract the last visit for each subject.

SUBJID VISIT

```
   40161       3  
   40161       4  
   40161       5  
   40161       6  
   40161       9  
   40201       3  
   40202       6  
   40202       8  
   40241       3  
   40241       4
```

The desired output is as follows

SUBJID VISIT

```
   40161     9  
   40201     3  
   40202     8
```

How should I do this in R? Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

While agstudy is correct, there is another way with the stats package and the aggregate function.

```
df <- read.table(text="SUBJID VISIT
40161 3
40161 4
40161 5
40161 6
40161 9
40201 3
40202 6
40202 8
40241 3
40241 4", header=TRUE)


aggregate(VISIT ~ SUBJID, df, max)

  SUBJID VISIT
1  40161     9
2  40201     3
3  40202     8
4  40241     4
```

Comment: +1. I prefer the formula method, though. To me, both the input and the output are much cleaner. `aggregate(VISIT ~ SUBJID, df, max)`.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your exellent answers. Actually I have more collums in my data set. How do I keep other collums after extracting the row corresponding to the last visit for each subject, such as follow up time and strata?   SUBJID VISIT  FollowUp Strata                                                              40161 3 29 1      
   40161 4 58 1     
   40161 5 92 1 
   40161 6 120 1 
   40161 9 210 1 
   40201 3 34 2  
   40202 6 98 2
   40202 8 182 2 
   40241 3 29 1
   40241 4 57 1

Comment: @user2077677 Well that depends on what your end goal is.  In the above example, you can assign the aggregation to a new variable, and keep the old one.  BTW the data you gave in the comment is unreadable, you might want to edit your question.

Comment: But woulnd't this give you just the maximum value and not the last value?

Answer (score 4):

To show another alternative, because I like the simplicity of its syntax, you can use `data.table` too. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "df":

```
library(data.table)
# data.table 1.8.7  For help type: help("data.table")
DT <- data.table(df, key = "SUBJID")
DT[, list(VISIT = max(VISIT)), by = key(DT)]
#    SUBJID V1
# 1:  40161  9
# 2:  40201  3
# 3:  40202  8
# 4:  40241  4
```

And, while we are sharing the many ways to do this in R, if you're comfortable with SQL syntax, you can also use `sqldf` as follows:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select SUBJID, max(VISIT) `VISIT` from df group by SUBJID")
  SUBJID VISIT
1  40161     9
2  40201     3
3  40202     8
4  40241     4
```

Answer (score 3):

Because we can, another base option:

```
 do.call(rbind,
         lapply(split(dat, dat$SUBJID), 
                function(x) tail(x$VISIT, 1) ) )
#      [,1]
#40161    9
#40201    3
#40202    8
#40241    4
```

---

**EDIT**

As @BenBolker suggests:

```
 do.call(rbind,
             lapply(split(dat, dat$SUBJID), 
                    function(x) tail(x, 1) ) )
```

should work for all columns if you have more.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your exellent answers. Actually I have more collums in my data set.

Comment: if this were changed to `tail(x,1)` it should work fine for all columns.

Answer (score 1):

Using `plyr` package for exmple:

```
 ddply(dat,.(SUBJID),summarise,VISIT=tail(VISIT,1))
  SUBJID VISIT
1  40161     9
2  40201     3
3  40202     8
4  40241     4
```

Where dat is :

```
dat <- read.table(text ='SUBJID VISIT
40161 3
40161 4
40161 5
40161 6
40161 9
40201 3
40202 6
40202 8
40241 3
40241 4',head=T)
```

Comment: to make this work for all columns, use `ddply(dat,.(SUBJID),tail,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution with `diff`:

```
dat[c(diff(dat$SUBJID) != 0, TRUE), ]

   SUBJID VISIT
5   40161     9
6   40201     3
8   40202     8
10  40241     4
```

It's also possible with `by`:

```
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$SUBJID, tail, 1))

      SUBJID VISIT
40161  40161     9
40201  40201     3
40202  40202     8
40241  40241     4
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be using `sqldf` package too,
    library(sqldf)

```
sqldf("SELECT SUBJID, MAX(VISIT) From df GROUP BY by SUBJID")

  SUBJID VISIT
1  40161     9
2  40201     3
3  40202     8
4  40241     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately (with @agstudy's data),

```
g <- grouping(df$SUBJID)
df[g[attr(g, "ends")],]

   SUBJID VISIT
5   40161     9
6   40201     3
8   40202     8
10  40241     4
```

or with data.table

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df), by="SUBJID", fromLast=TRUE)

   SUBJID VISIT
1:  40161     9
2:  40201     3
3:  40202     8
4:  40241     4
```